# Marketplace Credit Card Processing

Tags: transactions, payment-processing, marketplace

**Does anybody have any suggestions for a developer friendly credit card processor for a market place site?**

I am working on a UK marketplace style website to help cottage industry businesses start selling online. Customers can purchase products and services from our website, we take our fee, and then pass the rest onto the relevant business.

We are now at the stage where we're looking for payment processors that can offer the needed functionality. I discovered Amazon FPS Marketplace which is totally ideal ... except it is a US only service, grrr.

PayPal has a similar offering called Chained Payments (an example implementation can be found here: https://www.x.com/people/travis/blog/2010/08/17/how-to-make-a-chained-payment-using-nvp) but it can only pay money into PayPal accounts. We were rather hoping to be able to pay money directly into our clients' bank account.

Thanks everybody,

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long while since asking this question, but I wanted to return with an answer.

At the time I settled on using PayPal to send payments to merchants.

These days I've been using Stripe Connect which is significantly better than PayPal. The user experience is nicer, and integrating with their API is also super nice.

Answer (score 1):

Now re-reading I see you are are in the UK poundPay is only available in the US. 
there is another one called poundPay where you are not required to have any paypal accounts you can send e-checks. You have to request developer access. I am still waiting on my and it has been a week.